# Spring Batch: log when reader, processor and writer start

Tags: java, spring-batch

I need to print a log only once when the reader, processor and writer are running in a step. How can I do this so that the log is not printed every time a block of data is being processed?

**Batch class**

```
@Configuration
@EnableBatchProcessing
public class Batch
{
    @Autowired
    private JobBuilderFactory jobBuilderFactory;

    @Autowired
    private StepBuilderFactory stepBuilderFactory;

    @Autowired
    private ProcessorListener processorListener;

    @Autowired
    private WriterListener writerListener;


    @Autowired
    private MainJobExecutionListener mainJobExecutionListener;

    @Bean
    public Step step(Reader reader, Processor processor, Writer writer)
    {
        return stepBuilderFactory.get("step")
                .<Input, Output>chunk(10)
                .reader(reader)
                .processor(processor)
                .writer(writer)
                .faultTolerant().skipPolicy(new ExceptionSkipPolicy())
                .listener(processorListener)
                .listener(writerListener)
                .build();
    }

    @Bean
    public Job mainJob(Step step)
    {
        return jobBuilderFactory.get("mainJob")
                                .listener(mainJobExecutionListener)
                                .incrementer(new RunIdIncrementer())
                                .start(step)
                                .build();
    }
}
```

**Processor listener sample class**
I've got another listener class to writer.

```
@Log4j2
@Component
public class ProcessorListener implements ItemProcessListener<Input, Output>
{
    @Override
    public void beforeProcess(Input input)
    {
        log.info("step: start processor");
    }

    @Override
    public void afterProcess(Input input, Output output) { }

    @Override
    public void onProcessError(Input input, Exception e) { }
}
```

Comment: keep a flag somewhere "static boolean hasBeenProcessed". if  ( !hasBeenProcessed ) { log(); hasBeenProcessed = true; }

Comment: Finally, I've created a class with the singleton design pattern. In my case, using a static variable from a non-static method was not an acceptable option for business rules.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `@PostConstruct` annotation and log stuff there or just use it in the Constructor?

Comment: you are talking about construction of an object, not execution of a step. those constructors will be called, whether those steps will ever be executed or not, so it'll give wrong results